# Как исправить отправку сообщений на отправку сообщений через интернет

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, мобильная-разработка

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть приложение которое отправляет и выводит входящее сообщения на экран, есть необходимость отправлять сообщения по номеру телефона не как SMS, а через интернет. Аутентификация происходит в приложении через сервис Firebase по номеру телефона. Можно ли исправить код на отправку сообщения через интернет или реализовать отправку сообщения через сервис Firebase или каким-то другим образом используя интернет?
P.S. долго гуглил так ничего и не нашёл

Comment: По моему вам нужно смотреть в сторону `service` поскольку как вы получите сообщение по интернету в случае свернутого или закрытого приложения?

Comment: а можете посоветовать что почитать чтобы разобраться?

Comment: Для начала можете ознакомится с этой статьей например: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru